# C++ in UNIX when parsing an xml file using libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, unix, libxml2

How to retrieve node and attribute values from xml file in C++ using libxml2 by using xpath ?

Thanks in advance,
Bhargava

Comment: Did you see the examples provided on the libxml website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp1.xml:

```
<users noofids="1">
        <user user="vin" password="abc"/>
</users>
```

Program:

```
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char ID[25];
  xmlInitParser ();
  //LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
  xmlDoc *doc = xmlParseFile ("sp1.xml");
  xmlXPathContext *xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext (doc);
  xmlXPathObject *xpathObj =
    xmlXPathEvalExpression ((xmlChar *) "users/user", xpathCtx);
  xmlNode *node = xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[0];
  xmlAttr *attr = node->properties;
  while (attr)
    {
      //if(!xmlStrcmp(attr->name,(const xmlChar *)"noofids"))
      //sprintf(ID,"%s",attr->children->content);
      std::cout << "Attribute name: " << attr->name << "  value: " << attr->
    children->content << std::endl;
      attr = attr->next;
    }
  //std::cout<<"ID: "<<ID<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

i got output by trying by my own

Answer (score 8):

Since this is tagged C++ I'll assume you can use the libxml++ library bindings.

I wrote a simple program that:

- Parse the document using a `DomParser`
- Make an XPath query using `find()` on the document root node to get to the attribute.
- Cast the first node of the XPath result to an `Attribute` node
- Get that attribute string value using `get_value()`
- Display that value

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Glib;
using namespace xmlpp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Parse the file
    DomParser parser;
    parser.parse_file("file.xml");
    Node* rootNode = parser.get_document()->get_root_node();

    // Xpath query
    NodeSet result = rootNode->find("/root/a/b/@attr");

    // Get first node from result
    Node *firstNodeInResult = result.at(0);
    // Cast to Attribute node (dynamic_cast on reference can throw [fail fast])
    Attribute &attribute = dynamic_cast<Attribute&>(*firstNodeInResult);

    // Get value of the attribute
    ustring attributeValue = attribute.get_value();

    // Print attribute value
    cout << attributeValue << endl;
}
```

Given this input:

```
<!-- file.xml -->
<root>
  <a>
    <b attr="I want to get this"> </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

The code will output:

```
I want to get this
```

To compile this on an Unix system:

```
c++ `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --cflags` `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --libs` file.cpp
```

Comment: thans for reply, but i need same thing only in libxml2

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but isn't version 2 of libxml++ a wrapper for libxml2? So in practice this is libxml2. Is there any reasons that you cannot use a wrapper?

Comment: I don't know about wrappers so i didn't use it and May i know the use of wrappers?

Comment: Got a bunch of `undefined reference` when I tried to compile. Compiling like this fixed the issue for me (sorry the stupid lowercase tilde in stack overflow is screwing up the formatting...) <command start>c++ file.cpp `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --cflags` `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --libs`<command end>

Comment: Then trying to run the program errors: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to get the value for the xpath you are trying to evaluate with libxml++.

Based on Alexandre Jasmin's answer but his only shows how to print an xpath attribute and it's not trivial to figure out how to print the `Node`'s value because you have to cast it to a specific object (also his answer throws an exception).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Glib;
using namespace xmlpp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Parse the file
    DomParser parser;
    parser.parse_file("sample.xml");
    Node* root = parser.get_document()->get_root_node();

    // Xpath query
    NodeSet result = root->find("/root/ApplicationSettings/level_three");

    // Get first element from result
    Element *first_element = (Element *)result.at(0);

    // Print the content of the Element
    cout << first_element->get_child_text()->get_content() << endl;
}
```

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <ApplicationSettings>
        <level_three>hello world</level_three>
    </ApplicationSettings>
</root>
```

compile

```
g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --cflags` `pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --libs`
```

run

```
./test
```